# Set Click event in a SVG button

Tags: javascript

How do I set a .click() event in this SVG? To click automatically.

```html
<span style="margin-right: 15px;" id="play">
 <svg class="speechace-playback-30" aria-label="Start playing example audio" aria-pressed="false" role="button" viewBox="0 0 30 30" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle; outline: 0px;">
  <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="14" style="fill: rgb(69, 97, 26); stroke: rgb(69, 97, 26); stroke-width: 1;"></circle>
  <path d="M19.5,15 L12.75,11.102885682970026 L12.749999999999998,18.897114317029974 z" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 1; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
 </svg>
</span>
```

Comment: Automatically means. Do you want to perform a click event on that element periodically?

Comment: SVGElement.click() does not work?

Comment: I actually just deleted my answer that stated to use document.getElementById("play").click();. The .click method is only supported by some elements. I believe you would have to wrap a button element around your svg and then add the .click method to that button element.

Comment: SVGElement.click() does not work.

Answer (score 1):

write this in your js code. Try to cover svg with div tag

```html
document.getElementById("IdOfYourSvg").addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
//your logic
})
```

Comment: I wanna click on a setInterval. It's not working. I can`t change the code.

Comment: Why cant you do directly at setInterval? Can you explain your issue in more details .

Comment: When you click it plays a song. I can change the color every 5 seconds ```setInterval(function(){
            document.querySelector('circle').style.fill = "red";
        }, 5000);``` but I can't trigger the click event

Comment: try to wrap svg inside <a>

Comment: It's not working at all.